# Plain vanilla cursor in stored procedure won't compile

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

There is a very plain vanilla [documented stored proc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) (top result on google) that gives syntax errors when I try to create it in Workbench:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b, c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select id from product;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR select name from product;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur2;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    FETCH cur2 INTO c;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF b < c THEN
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,c);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END;
```

The only 2 lines I changed were `select id from product` and `select name from product`, so it would hit a table that actually exists in my database. When I try to create the stored proc (not even run it) I get this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 3

I have successfully created MySQL stored procs before, but never with a cursor in it, and I cannot seem to get the most basic cursor to work, even when copying/pasting right from mysql's website.

My objective is very simple: I want to be able to run a query in the stored proc, loop through the results in a cursor, and grab a value within each record of the loop, and do something with that value. For example

```
select id from product
```

And I'd like `SET @ID = id` type of thing, so I can grab `@ID` and do some things with that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the statement delimiter to a string that doesn't appear in the "create procedure" statement,  eg.   `DELIMITER $$`   then execute the `CREATE PROCDURE` statement, terminating the statement with `$$` (in place of the last semicolon)  then put the statement delimiter back to default semicolon  `DELIMITER ;`  Example here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html   changing the delimiter is necessary if running a vanilla SQL client like mysql command line client; some clients include a "procedure edit" that handles the delimiter "behind the scenes".

Comment: Thank you spencer, that solved it.